# Set multiple options in Chosen from JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using [chosen.js](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) for my multiselect dropdown. I want to set `multiple` `true` or `false` from JS, but I can't set it. How can I do that?

> HTML :

```
<select name="test" id="id">
   <option value="">-- Select an option --</option>
   <option class="item" name="test" value="21" data-url="URL">A</option>
   <option class="item" name="test" value="22" data-url="URL">B</option>
   <option class="item" name="test" value="23" data-url="URL">C</option>
</select>
```

> JS :

```js
require([
  'jquery',
  'chosen'
], function($, chosen) {
  $('#id').chosen({
    width: '100%',
    multiple: true,
    //multiple: 'multiple', also tried this
    placeholder_text: "Select Options"
  });
})
```

> **Note: I don't want to set it in the HTML code directly.**

**UPDATE (Output) :**

[image]

Comment: I don't believe Chosen lets you change the type of the `select` you apply the library to. It **has** to have the `multiple` attribute in the HTML in order to let you choose multiple options: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html#attributes

Comment: But, I can't able to select multiple value. I have same html structure as like mentioned in link. Is there any attribute to set from js?

Comment: @ankita patel, 
I am not able to understand your code properly, can you give the correct html and js so that I can help you

Comment: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ you have to give select element multiple attribute

Comment: @AnkitaPatel the `multiple` attribute *has* to be there; Chosen depends on it. You can add it programmatically through JS if required. I added an example of this in an answer below.

Comment: @BloodyProgrammer check my update please.

Comment: @ankita patel, yes i'm checking please wait

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to change the type of selection in the Chosen library itself. It's set using the `multiple` attribute on the HTML `select` element when the library is instantiated.

As you state that you don't want to, or cannot, amend the HTML:

> Note that I don't want to set it in the HTML code directly.

Then you could instead set the `multiple` attribute in JS before you define the Chosen library. You can also remove the first 'Select an option' item too, as it's not relevant to a multiple select.

```
var $select = $('#id').attr('multiple', true);
$select.find('option:first').remove();
$select.chosen({
  width: '100%',
  placeholder_text: "Select Options"
});
```

Comment: Using this, It's by default select "Select Options" value when page load. It should not be default selected.

Comment: Check ss in question please.

Comment: You can also remove the first `option` element. I updated the answer to show you how.

Comment: Spot on. Saved mb half an hour.